# Convert int type datetime to milliseconds

Tags: c, algorithm, datetime, math

The int type datetime is expressed as follows, `13:32:53:600 => 133253600`, and I wanna convert the int type datetime to the number of milliseconds that have passed since 0:00:00 of the day. For example, `133253600 => 48773600`.

Comment: It's `(((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60) + seconds) * 1000 + millis`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem is how to extract hour, min, sec and milis from the integer in 2 operations (as you have used 6 already)

Comment: How to extract them? `sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d:%d", &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &mills)`; OP isn't clear about the format: why convert to that concatention?

Comment: @WeatherVane My understanding of the question is that the input is the number 133253600, not a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane you do not have a string only **integer** HHMMSSTTT

Comment: @0___________ the OP clearly states "The int type datetime is expressed as follows, `13:32:53:600`" so I don't get they should be packed into that integer and then extracted.

Comment: @WeatherVane *"and I wanna convert the int type datetime"*

Comment: @WeatherVane do you know integer having costant `13:32:53:600`?

Comment: Which function gives date in that format? It's as bad as saying `int b = 10010010;` is "binary".

Comment: @0___________ clearly "13:32:53:600" is a string. **Which** time function gives that unusual integer format?

Comment: @WeatherVane *"expressed as follows"* = he simply explains what particular digits mean in the integer. The question subject is: ***"Convert int type datetime"***

Comment: did you try anything? For a start do tod%1000 (tod is the integer you have)

Comment: @royalgrasshopper my answer would be *don't pack it like that*. It reminds me of the student credit card problems where they convert the input string to `long` and then laboriously extract each digit. Please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4):

Consider a numeral in the form *HHMMSSmmm*, where *HH* is a decimal number of hours, *MM* is a decimal number of minutes *SS* is a decimal number of seconds, and *mmm* is a decimal number of milliseconds.

Interpreted as a decimal numeral of milliseconds, *HH*0000000 is more milliseconds than is in *HH* hours. There are 3,600,000 milliseconds in an hour, so 3,600,000•*HH* in *HH* hours, but *HH*0000000 represents 10,000,000•*HH* milliseconds. It has 6,400,000•*HH* milliseconds too many. Therefore, we can correct it by subtracting 6,400,000•*HH*.

Similarly, *MM*00000 represents 100,000•*MM* milliseconds, but there are only 60,000•*MM* milliseconds in *MM* minutes. It has 40,000•*MM* milliseconds too many, so we can correct it by subtracting 40,000•*MM*.

*SSmmm* does represent the number of milliseconds in *SS* seconds and *mmm* milliseconds, so no correction is needed for those.

We can easily find *HH* by dividing *HHMMSSmmm* by 10,000,000, using C’s truncating division. Isolating the minutes would require more work. Dividing by 100,000 would give us *HHMM*, and then we would need to take a remainder to separate *MM*. However, instead, we can rewrite the corrections to use *HHMM* directly.

Given some *x* that is *HHMMSSmmm*, we want *x* − *HH*•6,400,000 − *MM*•40,000. Adding and subtracting *HH*00•40,000 does not change the number, so:

- *x* − *HH*•6,400,000 − *MM*•40,000
- = *x* − *HH*•6,400,000 − *MM*•40,000 + *HH*00•40,000 − *HH*00•40,000
- = *x* − *HH*•6,400,000 + *HH*•100•40,000 − *MM*•40,000 − *HH*00•40,000
- = *x* − *HH*•(6,400,000 − 4,000,000) − *HHMM*•40,000.
- = *x* − *HH*•2,400,000 − *HHMM*•40,000.

As noted above, *HH* can be calculated in C as `x/10000000`, and *HHMM* can be calculated as `x/100000`.

Therefore, an expression that gives us the desired result is `x - x/10000000*2400000 - x/100000*40000`, which uses four multiplication/division operations and two additions/subtraction operations.

Comment: I'm shocked by your answer... You're such a genius!

Answer (score 0):

The result is calculated as follows:

```c
r = ( ( ( H * 60 ) + M ) * 60 ) + S ) * 1000 + milli;
```

So if we include getting the components, that's

```c
t = 133253600;

H = t / 10000000;
M = t / 100000 % 100;
S = t / 1000 % 100;
milli = t % 1000;

r = ( ( ( H * 60 ) + M ) * 60 ) + S ) * 1000 + milli;
```

But the seconds are technically already correct.

```c
t = 133253600;

H = t / 10000000;
M = t / 100000 % 100;
milli = t % 100000;

r = ( ( H * 60 ) + M ) * 60 + milli;
```

That is the required 8 ops. 4 divisions, 2 multiplications and 2 additions.

Comment: You have 6 multiplication/division operations while the question allows 5. And you're counting `%` as division, but it isn't clear if this operation is allowed.

Comment: @interjay, They also said more than 8 ops. I took the 5+3 distribution as an example. /// `%` is every bit as much a division as `/`. To be specific neither performs division by itself, but each returns a part of the result. `%` returns the remainder part, while `/` returns the whole part. Only together do they return the quotient. In fact, they are literally the same op in the CPU, which returns both parts. (Although the compiler will replace divisions by constant amounts with multiplications and shifts.)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Your answer is exactly what I got and I'm not able to optimize it anymore...

Comment: *"no more than 8 ops", I meant

Comment: Re "*I'm not able to optimize it anymore*" That is not  what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to divide by 10000000 (Only keeping integers) to get hours (the first 2 numbers), 100000 to get the first 4, 1000 to get the first 6, etc.
With tose numbers you then can make modulus 100 to get last 2 digits of that number and modulus 1000 to keep last 3. Last thing you have to do is transform those into miliseconds and that's it.

```
    int time=133253600 //example
    int hours = time/ 10000000;
    int minutes = (time/ 100000) % 100;
    int seconds = (time/ 1000) % 100;
    int milliseconds = time% 1000;

    int timeInMs = (hours * 3600000) + (minutes * 60000) + (seconds * 1000) + milliseconds;
```

It doesn't use 8 operations, but I can't imagine how could you do it on less. You could optimize by dividing by smaller numbers if you do one operation depending on the previous one, maybe.

Comment: I started writing my post before there was any answer, didn't reload the page before sending it. Didn't see it already was a better answer